# angular 2 view renders before data loads in ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, observable, fork-join

I use github API to load user and his followers data in my angular 2 app, but view renders before ngOnInit finishes load data and because of this I receive: 
`Cannot read property of undefined` error. My code fragment looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    Observable.forkJoin(
        this._githubService.getUser('kaxi1993'),
        this._githubService.getFollowers('kaxi1993')
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.user = res[0];
        this.followers = res[1];
    },
    null,
    () => {
        this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

if I write html code like this:

```
 <div *ngIf="user && user.avatar_url">
   <img class="media-object avatar" [src]="user.avatar_url" alt="...">
 </div>
```

works fine, but returns error `Cannot read property 'avatar_url' of undefined` when write html code without `*ngIf` like this:

```
<img class="media-object avatar" [src]="user.avatar_url" alt="...">
```

also note: `getFollowers` works fine, but if I move 
`getFollowers` before `getUsers` in `forkJoin` method then `getUsers` works fine and `getFollowers` need `*ngIf` to avoid error.
Is it possible to write without extra *ngIf code? any help guys, Thanks a lot.

Comment: The accepted answer only talks about avoiding the error. If you want to solve the root cause you can use a `resolver` for getting the API data before your component initializes. Check out [this](https://shermandigital.com/blog/wait-for-data-before-rendering-views-in-angular-2/) article.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the safe-navigation (Elvis) operator to avoid the error like

```
 <div *ngIf="user?.avatar_url">
   <img class="media-object avatar" [src]="user.avatar_url" alt="...">
 </div>
```

or

```
<img class="media-object avatar" [src]="user?.avatar_url" alt="...">
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, upvoted, but I'm interested is it ok when view renders before data loads in ngOnInit?

Comment: That's normal behavior. The call to the server can take "ages". Angular just renders the view when the component is created and updates it when data arrives (when the model is updated). There are feature requests for a lifecycle callback that waits for the template to render until a promise resolves but currently this is not supported.

Comment: Ok thank you, wish you good lucks ;)

Comment: This saved my bacon, but it blows that it works that way. Thus is life